# Specifying a part of font name

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

Is there any way to specifying a part of a font name and browser use first matched font?
For example I want let browser to use any font that has 'Garamond' in its name, e.g. Garamond Pro, Garamond Pro, ... .

Comment: Most users won't have Garamond installed on their computers as it isn't a standard system font.

Comment: @BillyMoat It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Not in HTML or in CSS. You would probably need both JavaScript and Flash in order to get a list of fonts in the user’s system, see e.g. [Getting a List of Installed Fonts with Flash and Javascript](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/).

With the name “Garammond”, you would probably not find anything. With “Garamond”, you would normally find just “Garamond” or nothing.